# Can I set mongoDB response time to fixed value?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, circuit-breaker

I want to test circuit breaker used in my project and I'd like to avoid sleeps and stuff and play the almost real scenario - that my mongoDB response time is slow. How can I force mongoDB responses to fixed time? Let it be 1 second?

Comment: why dont you implement the "fixed time" concept on your service layer? ie. if mongodb responds fast then you wait till the fixed time period on your service.

Comment: I want the test scenario to be as much close to real one as possible - slow response comes from MongoDB driver. Maybe stubbing the driver would be the answer